# Xcode 15 Build Fail because of AdMob - linker error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

**On the final step of uploading my game to App Store, while archiving the project in Xcode 15, my build fails because of the linker error and AdMob undefined symbols reason. There may be something wrong with the unity-plugin-library like on the screenshots.I think Xcode just cant find some files from my projects that are linked with Google AdMob Ads plugin. I got 2 errors and warnings**

The error is like this:
Unity Framework 2 issues
Undefined symbols:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
\_CGSizeFromGADAdSize, referenced from:
\+\[GADUPluginUtil safeAdSizeForAdSize:\] in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[14\] (GADUPluginUtil.o) \_GADAdSizeEqualToSize, referenced from:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUZb1.png)
+ \[GADUPluginUtil safeAdSizeForAdSize:\] in unity-plugin-library.a \[arm64\] \[14\] (GADUPluginUtil.o) GADAdSizeFromCGSize, referenced from: \__GAMUBannerViewSetValidAdSizes in unity-plugin-library.a \[arm64\]\[11\] (GADUInterface.o)
+ \[GADUPluginUtil safeAdSizeForAdSize:\] in unity-plugin-library.a \[arm64\] \[14\] (GADUPluginUtil.o) + \[GADUPluginUtil adSizeForWidth: height:\] in unity-plugin-library.a \[arm64\] \[14\] (GADUPluginUtil.o) GADAdSizeFullWidthPortraitWithHeight, referenced from:
+ \[GADUPluginUtil adSizeForWidth: height:\] in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[14\] (GADUPluginUtil.o) \_GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth, referenced from:
+ \[GADUPluginUtil adaptiveAdSizeForWidth: orientation:\] in unity-plugin-library.a \[arm64\] \[14\] (GADUPluginUtil.o) GADErrorUserInfoKeyResponseInfo, referenced from:
  GADUGetAdErrorResponse Info in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[11\] (GADUInterface.o)
  GADLandscapeAnchored Adaptive BannerAdSizeWithWidth, referenced from:
+ \[GADUPluginUtil adaptiveAdSizeForWidth: orientation:\] in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[14\] (GADUPluginUtil.o) GADPortraitAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth, referenced from:
+ \[GADUPluginUtil adaptiveAdSizeForWidth:orientation:\] in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[14\] (GADUPluginUtil.o) \_NSValueFromGADAdSize, referenced from:
  \_GAMUBannerViewSetValidAdSizes in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\]\[11\] (GADUInterface.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$\_GADAppOpenAd, referenced from:
  in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[9\] (GADUAppOpenAd.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$\__GADBannerView, referenced from:
  in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[10\] (GADUBanner.o)
  _OBJC_CLASS_$\_GADExtras, referenced from:
  in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[15\] (GADURequest.o) _OBJC_CLASS_$\_GADInterstitialAd, referenced from:
  in unity-plugin-library.a\[arm64\] \[12\] (GADUInterstitial.o)
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Error 1] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z04aV.jpg) [Error 2] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuVmX.png) [Error 3] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ0l4.jpg)  [Error 4] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcBM1.jpg)

I tried to add libraries or frameworks in the "Compile Sources" window in Build Phases in Xcode. I tried adding frameworks to "Link binary with Libraries". I tried adding "$inherited" to properties of one of the files. I tried restarting my Mac and XCode. At first I was building with Google AdMob unity plugin version 8.4.0 and I updated to the latest plugin 8.5.2 but the errors were the same.

My configuration:
Unity: 2021.3.31f1
AdMob: 8.5.2
Xcode: 15
MacOS: MacOS 14 latest
BaseSDK: IOS
Architecture: Arm64
Ruby: 3.2.2
CocoaPods: 1.13.0

Comment: Did you open the xcworkspace file in Xcode instead of the project file? You'll be able to tell since the workspace will include a Pods target. If you don't have a workspace file check the settings in the dependency manager and make sure the box to create it is checked.

Comment: I actually did not, I just opened the ".xcodeproj". Also youre right, the xcworkspace wasnt created in my project folder. That means I should check dependency manager to create it, and after that open the xcworkspace file in XCode and archive there or are there other steps? By the way thank you for trying to help

Comment: Building the workspace should just work. It'll download and build the pods first and then the rest.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have a box that says "create xcworkspace file". so it doesnt get generated in my project folder. There is a dropdown in External Dependency Manager in IOS Resolver with options: "XCode Workspace - Add cocoapods to the Xcode workspace", with what I get my problems above. Or " Xcode Project - Add Cocoapods to the Xcode project", after building with that option, I just get lots of errors while building in XCode like "expected a type" or "unknown name type" or "cannot find protocol" or " None - do not integrate Cocoapods", maybe Unity stopped generating .xcworkspace file?

Comment: The option to generate the workspace is "XCode Workspace - Add cocoapods to the Xcode workspace" If it isn't generating then it's possible there's an issue with cocoa pods. You might try the steps here and see if it helps: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-unity-to-build-an-xcode-workspace-or-xcworkspace-file.797922/#post-6435227

Comment: Got you, I will try to work on the problem with cocoapods because the .xcworkspace file is not being generated for me. Seems like reinstalling cocoapods and manually editing "Podfile" might help, but in the thread above those steps aren't very straightforward and I dont understand what should I do after editing the podfile, where should I type "pod install" command, because my terminal doesnt recognize it, will dig in it

Answer (score 0):

Errors happened because there was no .xcworkspace generated. I was able to solve this by following this amazing video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKvsG-_oIBM . After that, you will generate .xcworkspace file and not project one which will solve the errors.